# TRACE logging on iPhone

Tags: iphone, trace, nslog

I am new to iPhone and trying to learn the sequence of methods invoked during application loading time.

After some googling, I found this that seems to be adequate:
    NSLog(@"Begin %@ initWithNibName", [[self class]description]);
But is there a way to insert the method name instead of typing it myself? Is there even a better TRACE log command???

Also, I found this on the internet:

```
#define METHOD_LOG (NSLog(@"%@ %s\n%@", \
    NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), __FILE__, self))
```

But I don't know what it does and how to use it. I tried:
-(id) init {
    METHOD_LOG("init");
    ......
}

But doesn't compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this to log the current method or function (works for both):

```
NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
```

To use the macro you quoted, you just type:

```
METHOD_LOG;
```

Comment: Thank you. Your macro is very useful. I've been using it all the time now. Btw, what's the difference between @"%s" and @"%@". I tried googling it but google doesn't understand @ and %s.

Comment: `%@` prints an Objective-C object (such as an `NSString`) and `%s` prints a C-style null-terminated string. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html